# Cirqus: "Expected an event with sequence number 0." exception

Tags: cirqus

Every once in a while I receive exceptions in Cirqus when trying to process commands. It happens with different types of commands, however it always happens with this specific aggregate root type (let's say its a registration form). We haven't deleted events nor messed with the Events table in any way, so I'm wondering what else can cause the issue.

The exact (but anonymized) error message is: `Tried to apply event with sequence number 12 to aggregate root of type RegistrationForm with ID d863ac79-6bc0-480d-9d83-30b7696e7ea1 with current sequence number -1. Expected an event with sequence number 0.`

So for example to debug the latest instance of the exception I queried the database for this aggregate id and got 37 events in return. I then checked the sequences and the sequences seemed correct. I also checked that the global sequences were at least also chronologically correct. Then I checked to see if the "meta" column had a different global sequence than the record, but that also checked out OK.

What I find most confusing is that other registration forms are able to go through. Looking at our logs there's no pattern I can identify, and also it only happens about 3-5% of the time.

I guess what I'm wondering is: what can cause this issue? how can I debug it? how can I prevent it from happening in the future?

System specifics: We're running under .net 4.5, using Cirqus 0.63.12 (and then also tested on 0.66.4), using Postgres 9.4 as the database (and using v0.63.12 of the Cirqus.Postgres package).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue! It seems that the PostgreSQL event source's SQL code was missing an `Order By` clause and in some cases my events were being returned out of order. I submitted this pull request as a proposed fix to the problem: https://github.com/d60/Cirqus/pull/75